# When Video editing, importing a .PNG, how do I remove the outer edge artifact/black line that appears when resizing the image?

Tags: import, video

Thank you to whomever is reading this. I began using Blender in May of 2020 expressly for video editing and just recently began tinkering with 3D.

I have been making images in InkScape and exporting them as .PNG files to be used in Blender Video editing. When there is transparency involved the outer edge of the image will become a black or white line visible through whatever it Alphas Over. I have searched for existing Q&A for this question and I have been unable to find anything specific to this problem that applies to video.

The only solution I have been able to come up with is to crop 1 to 3 pixels off the image in all directs. This stretches the images slightly. When I am trying to use piece of a photograph this noticeably distorts the image.

Thanks again.

Edit: Great idea wilks, thank you. Here is a render of my most recent issue. Each of the 6 "I am..." name tags is a separate image sized to 720 x 1290 with a transparent background. I removed crop from the bottom right image that reads Forgiven and there is now a white line running through the top left and top centers images. The images the white line does not appear in are in higher number channels and my understanding is they are effectively in front of bottom right name tag.

[image: example]

OS: WIN 10 64bit
CPU: Intel i5-4570 CPU @ 3.20ghz
GPU: GeForce GTX 760
RAM: 16GB

Edit: Thank you susu for the suggestion. GIMP exported the images without generating a border. makes me wonder what the difference between them is.

that said if anyone comes up an inkscape solution that would be awesome...my brain is about full, not sure how many new programs I can learn :)

Comment: hi, could you post a screenshot of what you mean?

Comment: Try exporting as a different format (not png).